# Custom Validator Help Angular 14

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-custom-validators

I've been hung up on really understanding how to implement a custom validator inside of my reactive form.

I have 15 fields, 3 in which pertain to the custom validator "tcpPorts", "udpPorts", and "icmp" which is a check box. The logic that I want implemented is that at least ONE of these three fields have a value to be able to submit. At least one is required along with the other fields in the form.

How do I construct the right validator for this?

componen.ts my form

```
 newFWXForm = this.fb.group(
{
  sspSelect: ["", Validators.required],
  requester: [this.loggedInUser],
  requesterContactInfo: [this.loggedInUserEmail],
  fwxDescription: ["", Validators.required],
  durationTypeSelect: ["Permanent", Validators.required],
  durationDate: [""],
  infraSelect: [""],
  sourceIPs: ["", Validators.required],
  DestAnyCheck: [false],
  SrcAnyCheck: [false],
  icmp: [false, atleastOneValidator()],
  destinationIPs: ["", Validators.required],
  tcpPorts: ["", atleastOneValidator()],
  udpPorts: ["", atleastOneValidator()],
  addDirectory: new FormControl(false),
},
{ Validators: [] }
```

);

here is also a custom Validator function I started and tried a lot of different logic inside, help and knowledge would be greatly appreciated!

```
export function atleastOneValidator(): ValidatorFn {
return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {};
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: a Simple Logical check on those three fields inside your function should do the trick

Comment: Okay good to know im almost there. Thank you. How will the function know which form Control names I am trying to specify when doing my if logic? Do I have to add some type of getter inside of the function? and then define a variable? I know Abstract Control is in there for maybe that reason. Sorry for the question, I'm just confused.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Validator for the `FormGroup` that checks the value of the 3 child FormControls.

It could be something like this.

```
export function atleastOneValidator(controlsNames: string[]): ValidatorFn {
  return (group: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
  // Here include your validation logic of the controls. Im just checking for one truthy.
  const isValid = controlsNames.some(
    (fieldName) => group.get(fieldName)?.value
  );

  return isValid ? null : { atleastOneValidator: true };
};
```

}

And then add it to the FormGroup validators with passing an array of control names to check.

```
newFWXForm = this.fb.group(
  {
    ... //your controls 
  },
  { 
    validators: [atleastOneValidator(['icmp', 'tcpPorts', 'udpPorts'])]
  }
)
```

Cheers